# Simple XSLT Question: How can I add the closing "/" at the end of a single tag?

Tags: xslt, xhtml

I'm teaching myself XSLT and am still trying to wrap my brain around the small details.  I have a template in my XSL stylesheet that looks like this...

```
<td><img src="{normalize-space(image)}"/></td>
```

which produces XHTML that looks like this...

```
<td><img src="somefile.jpg"></td>
```

How do I change my XSL template to add a trailing "/" to the img tag so that the XHTML output looks like this...

```
<td><img src="somefile.jpg"/></td>
```

Also, why does the trailing slash in the template get omitted in the output?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with this:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
   doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" indent="yes"/>
```

This will get your XSL parser to close empty tags correctly since you are (technically) producing XML.  HTML does not have the concept of an empty tag like XML/XHTML does.

Comment: thanks! i was getting an that said "The server did not understand the request, or the request was invalid.  Error processing resource 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd".  So I removed the doctype-system attribute and now it fixed the problem with omitting the '/', but now I'm receiving an error on line 2 of the output XHTML "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" that says "Required white space was missing".  Your thoughts?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Try removing the doctype-system attribute and doctype-public for a start.  If your output doesn't need to go through a validator, this should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
<xsl:element name="img">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">blarg</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

which will output `<img src="blarg"/>`